# Discrete Morse theory, choice of Morse function, and removing noise

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology, data-analysis, computational-topology, persistent-homology

If I have a simplicial complex, and a discrete Morse function defined on the simplices, I can use *persistent homology* to produce a *barcode* which helps me distinguish "persistent" shape from noise. To quote H. Edelsbruner and J. Harer in [Persistent homology — a survey](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/edelhare.pdf) (Contemporary Mathematics 453, AMS, 2008).

> Persistent homology is an algebraic method for measuring topological
>   features of shapes and of functions. Small size features are often
>   categorized as noise and much work on scientific datasets is concerned
>   with de-noising or smoothing images and other records of observation.
>   But noise is in the eye of the beholder...

What if I chose my own Morse function? This may be necessary when looking at complex networks, such as social networks, and therein trying to de-noise the topology of their clique complexes. No Morse function is naturally available, since the simplices are higher-order structure (only the network edges have weights, and even this is not necessary for simple relation networks based on "actors" and "have met").

**What conditions does such a function need to be directly relevant to this process?** What are the main intuitive ideas which lead to a Morse function, defined on a simplicial complex, successful applicable in persistent homology?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You are free to define "your own Morse function" on a given clique complex, but I have no idea what it means for your Morse function to be "relevant to this process". Which process? Regarding the last sentence, you can use a filtered version of discrete Morse theory to speed up persistent homology computation: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-013-9529-6. See also Uli Bauer's thesis: http://webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/diss/2011/bauer_u/bauer_u.pdf

Comment: Ok, so I understand more now that the Morse theory helps you preprocess the complex. Then you do the persistent homology. Any Morse function will lead to a new complex which is homotopy equivalent to the unprocessed complex, is that right?

Comment: Ok I am reading the notes of your course on discrete Morse theory. The whole point is to reduce the size.

Comment: Maybe the methods in the following links can help to design an algorithmic way to construct discrete Morse function:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233835814_Constructing_discrete_Morse_functions